# Nuxt 3 Apollo query do not refresh on route change

Tags: graphql, nuxt.js, apollo, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I am using `useAsyncQuery` and it's simple like https://apollo.nuxtjs.org/ example:

```
const { data } = await useAsyncQuery(query, variables)
```

It works fine on page landing / page refresh.
As soon as you click on a `<NuxtLink />` you get a 400 error.

Many old questions are related to Nuxt 2, old solutions suggest to use `v-if="data"` on the page / component, or reassign the variable either as `const myVariable = data?.value?.entry` or declare `myVariable = ref()` first, or use `{ watch: [data] }` in query, but nothing makes any difference (maybe just avoid the error and leave a white page).

It also seems a confused topic where no unique proper answer is given.
Am I just trying to use something not fit for purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a different test I tried [nuxt-graphql-client](https://nuxt-graphql-client.web.app) instead.

This time I was using a public schema and everything worked.
As soon as I used a token, to access a private one, I got the same errors previously experienced with apollo on route change.

At this point I found an option in the `nuxt-graphql-client` documentation, which is `retainToken: true`.

Adding that fixed the issue.
Something similar might exist for apollo (though I could not find it) but, at this point, I might as well stick to nuxt-graphql-client.